# Running GET Request Through Rails on separate thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, multithreading

I have a get request that retrieves JSON needed for graphs to display on a page. I'd do it in JQuery, but because of the API that I am using, it is not possible -- so I have to do it in rails.

I'm wondering this: If I run the get request on a separate thread in the page's action, can the variable then be passed to javascript after the page loads? I'm not sure how threading works in rails.

Would something like this work:

```
Thread.new do
        url = URI.parse("http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTAMatch_570/GetMatchHistory/v001/?key=#{ENV['STEAM_WEB_API_KEY']}&account_id=#{id}&matches_requested=25&game_mode=1234516&format=json")
        res = Net::HTTP::get(url)
        matchlist = JSON.parse(res)
        matches = []
        if matchlist['result'] == 1 then
            matchlist['result']['matches'].each do |match|
                matches.push(GetMatchWin(match['match_id']))
            end
        end

        def GetMatchWin(match_id, id)
            match_data = matchlist["result"]["matches"].select {|m| m["match_id"] == match_id}
        end
    end
end
```

Given that the above code is in a helper file, and it then gets called in the action for the controller as such:

```
def index
  if not session.key?(:current_user) then
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    gon.winlossdata = GetMatchHistoryRawData(session[:current_user][:uid32])

  end
end
```

The "gon" part is just a gem to pass data to javascript.